# c++ - How to implement a destructor of an object that uses itself in the constructor

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, pointers, memory-management

I'm trying to make the Thompson's construction algorithm in c++ (I'm somewhat new to the language). But I'm having some difficulties on implementing a destructor for my class `NFiniteAutomaton`. In some part of the constructor of `NFiniteAutomaton` I have:

```
NFiniteAutomaton() = default;
NFiniteAutomaton(std::string regex){
    // A lot of code here
    //  ....
    NFiniteAutomaton single_ele;
    single_ele.init_state = new State;
    single_ele.final_state = new State;
    // A lot of code here
    //  ....
}
```

Then in other parts of my code, I create pointers to `single_ele.init_state`'s and `single_ele.final_state`'s content in the main `NFiniteAutomaton`, because I want to reuse states instead of creating new ones with the same attributes.
The struct `State` looks like this:

```
struct State;
struct Transition {
    State* to;
    std::string symbol;
};

struct State{
    std::vector<Transition> transitions;
};
```

So when I implement a destructor of `NFiniteAutomaton` that deletes all structs allocated on the heap, my problem is generated, because when `single_ele` gets out of the scope, it deletes all `State` pointers including the ones that other automata are using (because destructor gets called). One solution that I thought is to make a method `Clear()` that deletes all pointers whenever I want, and leave the default destructor. There is a way to implement the destructor of this class only using raw pointers?

Comment: I think there needs to be more concrete examples of what you're doing with `NFiniteAutomaton`. To me, automata should be self contained and fully encapsulated, never sharing states with anything else. Obviously not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One solution that I thought is to make a method `Clear()` that deletes all pointers whenever I want, and leave the default destructor.

Possible but why create a new function that the user of the class should be aware of instead of making the destructor take care of de-allocating dynamic memory? I wouldn't do that.

You should set your pointers to [nullptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr), before the destructor of `NFiniteAutomaton` is called. In the destructor use `delete` for init and final state.

Comment: I didn't know deleting a nullptr was safe. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make `single_ele` object persistent outside the constructor, define it as a class property rather than as a local object. The destructor can do its normal cleanup (no need for `Clear()` function), and the object will call the destructor only at the end of your program.

```
class NFIniteAutomaton {
 protected:
  static NFIniteAutomaton single_ele;
  ...
};
```